# Как сделать чтобы блок не залазил на другой и была прокрутка в этом блоке?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы блок не залазил на другой и была прокрутка в этом блоке?

```css
html {
    background: black;
}

.block1 {
    background: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}

.block2 {
    background: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
}

.block3 {
    background: green;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
}

.block2_block {
    margin: 7px 50px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>BIRDFARM</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
  <style>
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#fff;}
::-moz-placeholder          {color:#fff;}/* Firefox 19+ */
:-moz-placeholder           {color:#fff;}/* Firefox 18- */
:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#fff;}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2">
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    <div class="block2_block"></div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.block2 {
    /* ваш стиль */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: А как растянуть block2 между block1 и block3 ? Чтобы при масштабировании блок растягивался? Если я делаю 100vh для block2, то он заползает на block3

Comment: Как это он заползает на блок3? Не понял. Он не заползает если добавить 100vh

Comment: Вот у меня 2 блок высотой 600px и если я увеличиваю масштаб в браузере, то он так и остается высотой 600px, а как сделать чтоб он занимал всю высоту от 1 до 2 блока?

Comment: Т.е. вам надо, чтобы при масштабировании (Ctrl + колесо мыши) блок всегда имел высоту на весь экран?

Comment: Я посмотрел, он растягивается при этом на всю высоту. Удалите 1й блок и поставьте body{margin:0;} чтобы не мешал, все растягивается как при изменении размера окна, так и при изменении его масштаба (в хроме)

Comment: Вот смотрите, у меня есть block1 и block3, между ними есть block2, мне нужно чтобы block2 находился строго между ними, а если делать 100vh, то block2 находится под block3, а мне нужно чтобы block2 был строго между ними

Comment: Как это блок2 с 100vh находится под блоком3... У меня все норм, он между ними

Comment: Может вы создадите новый вопрос с интерактивным примером? там и видно будет?

Comment: Все, извиняюсь, у меня была ошибка в коде, теперь все нормально